# CMutablePointer<CString> to String in swift-language

Tags: string, swift, cstring

I have a library which has a function like this:

```
int get_user_name(const char **buffer);
```

in swift, should call like this:

```
var name:CMutablePointer<CString> = nil
get_user_name(name)
```

I want make use this function more comfortable so I wrapped this up:

```
func get_username() -> String {
    var name:CMutablePointer<CString> = nil
    get_user_name(name)

    // how to convert name to String
}
```

I question is how to convert name to String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It goes something like:

```
 var stringValue :CString = ""

 name.withUnsafePointer {p in
      stringValue = p.memory
 }

 return NSString(CString: stringValue)
```

Comment: The `CMutablePointer<T>` generic has a method called `withUnsafePointer` that yields an `UnsafePointer<T>` to the block you give it (p here is an `UnsafePointer<CString>`).  `UnsafePointer<T>` has a property `memory` that is of type `T` and gives you access to the value the pointer points to.  You can't save the `UnsafePointer` from the block, it's only good within the block, so you have to copy its value out there.

Comment: Thank you! where I can find  documents for Cstring/CMutablePointer?

Comment: I got this from the headers and reading here, the docs don't say anything about this at the moment...

Comment: Apple give so little about how to integrate old C library to swift.

Comment: I think they'd rather you didn't, it defeats the purpose of having this awesome type-safe language if you're spending all your time copying bytes to and from UnsafePointers, I suspect they have a 3-year goal of killing with fire all the old C-isms.

Comment: One more question, what's the relationship between swift and cocoa. can I consider cocoa as stdlib/socket/...etc for swift.

Comment: For a some more documentation take a look into "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C"

Comment: There is a chapter in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" called "Interacting with C APIs", which gives a little bit of information, but absolutely no mention of withUnsafePointer or how to actually use the C APIs.  Since large swaths of Apple's frameworks are C APIs, I believe we are all stuck with this hacky structure until they update them one day.  Hopefully they document these processes more fully in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
return NSString(UTF8String: name[0])
```